# python check if sequence is "almost" geometric

Tags: python, math, sequence, data-processing

Generally speaking, we can say a sequence is "almost constant" at a glance, e.g.

```
[1, 1, 1.01, 1, 1]
[3.32, 3.33, 3.37, 3.35, 3.34]
```

It feels harder for arithmetic sequence, and even harder for geometric.

Given the sequence

```
    [0.228983, 0.459001, 0.918014, 1.835991, 3.672006, 7.335999, 14.688007]
```

I need to check if it is "almost geometric".
Here is my final solution:

```
    >>> delt
    array([0.228983, 0.459001, 0.918014, 1.835991, 3.672006, 7.335999, 14.688007])
    >>> np.diff(np.log(delt))
    array([0.69540462, 0.69316025, 0.69312703, 0.69315372, 0.69205549, 0.69423771])
```

I'm not sure if this is a trival case. It saved me from the tedious work of dividing elements one by one -- a lot commands needs a lot typing.

PS. I'm posting this for sharing, any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: @PaulH as I mentioned, no question. I read stackoverflow's help, which says I can answer my own question, and posted questions can help me to remember my works. So I posted this for sharing.

Comment: @Catau If you're answering your own question, ou should post your answer as an answer to your question, not put the answer in the question.

Comment: @Catau This seems like trivia

Comment: Would you count 1,-2,4,-8,16... as geometric?

Comment: em...so my solution is not correct upon negative common ratio, I need another `np.abs()`

Answer (score 0):

A little supplement:

```
    >>> np.std([0.69540462, 0.69316025, 0.69312703, 0.69315372, 0.69205549, 0.69423771])
    0.0010511610420810475
```

this measures how much the sequence is close to a constant sequence.